# Powershell start excel automatically escaping spaces

Tags: powershell

I have written a Powershell script (GetMyTimesheet.ps1) that figures out the name and location of an excel file based on today's date. The most relevant lines:

```
$sheetName = '"Project Timesheet - ' + $currentMonth + ' ' + (get-date).year + ' - Billy Bob.xlsm"'
start excel $sheetName
```

On my computer, this works as expected and opens an excel file with the computed filename. However, when this same powershell code is run on my colleague's computer, Excel comes back with an error saying:

```
Sorry, we couldn't find Project%20Timesheet%20-%20February%202019%20-%20Billy%20Bob.xlsm. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
```

The problem seems to be that when the start excel $sheetName command is run on his computer, every space in $sheetName is escaped / replaced with %20. Why could that be happening? Any way to make it not happen?

Possibly relevant, the .ps1 file here is generated by a batch file (deploy.bat). I've checked though and the code contained in the generated file is identical. Also it's run by a compiled Autohotkey executable that Windows 10 initially throws an error about because it doesn't recognize it / thinks it might be malicious. This is all that does though:

```
if !FileExist("GetMyTimesheet.ps1")
    RunWait, deploy.bat

Run C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "GetMyTimesheet.ps1"
```

EDIT: Posting full code for reference - Powershell:

```
H:
cd Engineering
cd "# Timesheets"
cd (get-date).year
$test = Get-ChildItem | Where{$_.PSIsContainer} | Select Name
$month = $test| Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Last 1
cd $month.Name
#dir
#pause
$monthList = "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
$currentMonth = $monthList[[int]$month.Name-1]
$sheetName = '"Project Timesheet - ' + $currentMonth + ' ' + (get-date).year + ' - Billy Bob.xlsm"'
start excel $sheetName
```

Batch file that writes that .ps1:

```
echo off

set /p name="Enter your name exactly as it appears on the timesheet excel file: " 


(echo H:
echo cd Engineering
echo cd "# Timesheets"
echo cd ^(get-date^).year

echo $test = Get-ChildItem ^| Where{$_.PSIsContainer} ^| Select Name

echo $month = $test^| Sort-Object -Property Name ^| Select-Object -Last 1

echo cd $month.Name
echo #dir
echo #pause

echo $monthList = "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
echo $currentMonth = $monthList[[int]$month.Name-1]

echo $sheetName = '"Project Timesheet - ' + $currentMonth + ' ' + (get-date).year + ' - %name%.xlsm"'

echo start excel $sheetName) > GetMyTimesheet.ps1
```

Comment: %20 is URI encoding for a space character. Could you post your full code? Is the second person attempting to open the file trying to open the file on your machine via  a call to windows' explorer.exe or web browser?

Comment: Hey @trebleCode I've edited the post to include the full code. And no, basically the excel file is on a shared network drive (H: on both machines) that he has the same access to as I do.

Comment: Also sorry in advance if the code is kind of bad - I'm not overly experienced in PS, AHK, or bat programming and was just kind of hacking at it until it did what I wanted on my machine.

Comment: I would run the bat file from their machine, then step through the code in the .ps1 script in the ISE and check values in variables

Comment: Hmm but from the error message I can pretty much tell what the variable values were - the correct month, year, name etc is appearing in the filename it says it's looking for. I can reproduce the error by going into the PS code on my machine and replacing all the spaces with %20. The issue is that all spaces, even the ones that are explicitly entered in static strings are being replaced with %20 at start excel $sheetName, but obviously there's no filename with a bunch of %20's in it.

Comment: So what is different about your colleague's computer? OS version? PS version? Excel version?

Comment: Will investigate that though these are our work laptops that were all brought in at about the same time and should in theory have identical installations of everything - I have found so far that it does work perfectly on a different colleague's computer, and on the problem colleague's system if you just hardcode the path string to the file in $sheetName, it will also work fine. It just seems to be an issue with how I'm building the filename.

Comment: You do not specify the full path and filename in `$sheetName`. This could be a reason for Excel not being able to find the file on your colleagues computer.
Also, the file name is quite long and Excel could have problems with the filename being too long. Try using a shorter path.

Comment: Hey Theo - the code doesn't specify the full path in $sheetName. It navigates to the directory first and then just constructs the file name. We were only able to get it to work on the problem computer by actually explicitly specifying the full path in $sheetName, but on all other computers the code as is works fine.